smbios table header invalid?
i have this hardware id spoofer im working on, and the thing is that i get this result running it
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=0, Length=26
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=0, Length=26
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=71, Length=73
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=71, Length=73
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 71
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=47, Length=48
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=47, Length=48
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 47
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=51, Length=51
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=51, Length=51
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 51
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=49, Length=51
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=49, Length=51
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 49
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=110, Length=97
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=110, Length=97
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 110
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=68, Length=69
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=68, Length=69
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 68
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=0, Length=2
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=0, Length=2
ProcessTable: Vendor string is NULL
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=15, Length=14
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=15, Length=14
ProcessTable: Unsupported SMBIOS header type 15
Processing SMBIOS header: Type=101, Length=0
ProcessTable: header length is zero
Failed to process SMBIOS table: Status=0xc0000001


and here is my spoofer code
NTSTATUS LoopTables(void* mapped, ULONG size) {
    char* endAddress = (char*)mapped + size;

    while (1) {
        SMBIOS_HEADER* header = (SMBIOS_HEADER*)mapped;

        // Add debugging output
        DbgPrint("Processing SMBIOS header: Type=%d, Length=%d\n", header->Type, header->Length);

        if (header->Type == 127 && header->Length == 4) {
            DbgPrint("Reached end of SMBIOS tables.\n");
            break;
        }

        NTSTATUS status = ProcessTable(header);
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
            DbgPrint("Failed to process SMBIOS table: Status=0x%x\n", status);
            return status;
        }

        char* end = (char*)mapped + header->Length;
        if (end >= endAddress) {
            DbgPrint("Reached end of mapped memory.\n");
            break;
        }


        mapped = end;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

i tried this code and its supposed to change smbios but it didnt actually work for some reason and i have NO IDEA why but it should work, it might be cause smbios isnt in memory maybe but ive seen spoofers with this type of spoofing

https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Management_BIOS#:~:text=The%20first%20SMBIOS%20header%20is,not%20included%20in%20the%20length.  "The value of type indicates what element the structure contains information about. length indicates the size of header + data table. The strings are not included in the length." So you need to parse each element individually to account for strings. I think there might also be a padding/alignment requirement but I'm not 100% sure about that.
